# How to solve this problem efficiently?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have this problem
\begin{align}
           \min_{\alpha,\beta,X}~&<\alpha \cdot X+\beta \cdot Y,D>-c \cdot (<\alpha \cdot X+\beta \cdot Y,H>)^{1/2}\\
&X,\alpha,\beta>=0\
\end{align}
Where X,Y,D,H are semi-definite matrices.
How can I solve this problem efficiently? 
If we assume that we know the variable X, i.e. the above problem is

\begin{align}
           \min_{\alpha,\beta}~&<\alpha \cdot X+\beta \cdot Y,D>-c \cdot (<\alpha \cdot X+\beta \cdot Y,H>)^{1/2}\\
&\alpha,\beta>=0\
\end{align}
How to solve it efficiently? Is it possible to find a close form for the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem boils down to a form
$$
\min_{\alpha, \beta} \;\alpha \cdot c_{1} + \beta \cdot c_{2} - c \cdot \sqrt{(\alpha \cdot c_{3} + \beta \cdot c_{4})},
$$
where $c_{1}, c_{2}, c_{3}, c_{4} \ge 0$ (by the positive semidefiniteness of the involved matrices).

The square root is a concave function over its domain (here its argument is guaranteed to be nonnegative).
Hence, the entire objective is convex in $[\alpha, \beta]^{T}$. 
It can be solved efficiently.

Comment: Sorry, I missed one variable. But even without the variable X, how to solve it efficiently. Is it possible to find the answer in close form?Thank you.

Comment: would you please tell me how to solve it?